# Update column of database table with numeric value column of the same table in MySql

Tags: mysql

The MySQL version is

```
mysql> 
SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.17    |
+-----------+
1 row in set
```

With *LOAD DATA* syntax inserting into table `text_table` a csv file compiled by an external company

This is the `text_table`

**Image 1**

[image]

After *LOAD DATA* I need update the column `sID_Branch` with number value contains of columns `sBranch`, in this mode

All the next rows before the next `sBranch` should also be updated with that same id

**Image 2**

[image]

It's not possible to know in advance how many branches or rows number the csv file are contains, but at this moment there is no alternative to populate the table `text_table`

Any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance for any help

My table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `text_table`;
CREATE TABLE `text_table` (
  `sBranch` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID_Branch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of text_table
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Branch 1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('- London', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Pepsi', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Coca Cola', '1', '4');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Dr Pepper', '1', '5');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('- Springfield', '1', '6');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Fanta', '1', '7');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Duff', '1', '8');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Branch 2', '2', '9');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('- Manchester', '2', '10');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Heineken', '2', '11');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Dreher', '2', '12');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Ceres', '2', '13');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('- Mexico DF', '2', '14');
INSERT INTO `text_table` VALUES ('Corona', '2', '15');
```

**Edit #1**

```
+---------------+------------+-----+
| sBranch       | sID_Branch | sID |
+---------------+------------+-----+
| Branch 1      | NULL       |   1 |
| - London      | NULL       |   2 |
| Pepsi         | NULL       |   3 |
| Coca Cola     | NULL       |   4 |
| Dr Pepper     | NULL       |   5 |
| - Springfield | NULL       |   6 |
| Fanta         | NULL       |   7 |
| Duff          | NULL       |   8 |
| Branch 2      | NULL       |   9 |
| - Manchester  | NULL       |  10 |
| Heineken      | NULL       |  11 |
| Dreher        | NULL       |  12 |
| Ceres         | NULL       |  13 |
| - Mexico DF   | NULL       |  14 |
| Corona        | NULL       |  15 |
+---------------+------------+-----+
15 rows in set
```

**Update table**

```
+---------------+------------+-----+
| sBranch       | sID_Branch | sID |
+---------------+------------+-----+
| Branch 1      |          1 |   1 |
| - London      |          1 |   2 |
| Pepsi         |          1 |   3 |
| Coca Cola     |          1 |   4 |
| Dr Pepper     |          1 |   5 |
| - Springfield |          1 |   6 |
| Fanta         |          1 |   7 |
| Duff          |          1 |   8 |
| Branch 2      |          2 |   9 |
| - Manchester  |          2 |  10 |
| Heineken      |          2 |  11 |
| Dreher        |          2 |  12 |
| Ceres         |          2 |  13 |
| - Mexico DF   |          2 |  14 |
| Corona        |          2 |  15 |
+---------------+------------+-----+
15 rows in set
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see the image **number 2** on the question

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are asking. So what I understood was: You have a CSV file with two data columns "sBranch" and "sId" that you loaded into your database as shown on image 1 "text_table" than you ask how to update the column "sID_Branch" but what is not clear is based on what information should the column "sID_Branch" be updated with? My guess is from the "sBranch" description with the number on it? But Im not sure, again it is not clear!

Comment: I get it, but would be much easier to do that in PHP.

Comment: And please, don't use images. Just add the tables and values as text so whoever helps you can use it on their experiments.

Comment: @JorgeCampos many thanks for reply. The column `sID_Branch` be updated with the value of number contains in the column `sBranch`. If the value of number in the column `sBranch` is 1, the column `sID_Branch` be updated with value 1. If the value of number in the column `sBranch` is 2, the column `sID_Branch` be updated with value 2

Comment: So are the values `Branch 1`, `Branch 2`, ...  and this pattern is consistent?

Comment: Ok, that much I understood, so you have to add that to your question so it is clear. And also I'm assuming, given the data, that all the next rows before the next "sBranch" should also be updated with that same id. If that is correct please edit your question and add this details on it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos please see **edit #1** in the question I have added the tables and values as text and edit question and add this details on it

Comment: @forpas thanks for reply in this moment this pattern is consistent, but don't have alternative

Comment: @Kooper does it have to be a clean MySQL? Isn't it better to preprocess the file with `PHP` or `awk`?

Comment: @FlashThunder I'm using C# ASP NET with MySQL... not PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SET @tempid := 0;
UPDATE `text_table` SET `sID_Branch` = CASE WHEN `sBranch` like 'Branch%' THEN (@tempid := @tempid + 1) ELSE @tempid END;
```

Please note that it assumes that Branches are increasing by 1 every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this one here just as a source of knowledge in case you need, Flash Thunder's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977797/460557) is way cleaner.

Assuming that the pattern is consistent (it doesn't matter the increment in my case)

```
update text_table t
   inner join
(
select sBranch, 
       case when (sBranch REGEXP 'Branch \d*') = 1 
            then @curBranch := trim(replace(sBranch, 'Branch ', ''))
            else @curBranch end branchId,
       sID
  from text_table,
       (select @curBranch := null) a
) x on t.sID = x.sID
  set t.sID_Branch = x.branchId;
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a28ac0/1

Answer (score 0):

Use window function SUM() to number the branches:

```
UPDATE text_table t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, SUM(sBranch LIKE 'Branch %') OVER (ORDER BY sID) grp
  FROM text_table
) s ON s.sID = t.sID
SET t.siD_Branch = s.grp
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7c9a4c646cdc791d17ab82b1c2ae18b).
Results:

```
> sBranch       | sID_Branch | sID
> :------------ | ---------: | --:
> Branch 1      |          1 |   1
> - London      |          1 |   2
> Pepsi         |          1 |   3
> Coca Cola     |          1 |   4
> Dr Pepper     |          1 |   5
> - Springfield |          1 |   6
> Fanta         |          1 |   7
> Duff          |          1 |   8
> Branch 2      |          2 |   9
> - Manchester  |          2 |  10
> Heineken      |          2 |  11
> Dreher        |          2 |  12
> Ceres         |          2 |  13
> - Mexico DF   |          2 |  14
> Corona        |          2 |  15
```